# how to transform the json to json and fetch some of the attribute values of that json by using xslt

Tags: json, xslt

unable to fetch the value of the attribute in json by using xslt. For example I want to get the
value of the 1st index of the members array or value of the "squadName" and the output should be in json format.

json file as below

```
{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
      "powers": ["Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "age": 39,
      "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`

Comment: Are you using an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon HE 11 where you can use e.g. `-json:file.json` to feed a JSON document as the input to your XSLT 3 code? Or which XSLT processor do you use, how to you feed the JSON to XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/xpath-31#lookup-operator for selecting properties in XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 maps or items in XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 arrays, assuming you feed that input JSON as the initial match selection to your XSLT 3 code you can just select e.g. `?members?1` "to get the value of the 1st index of the members array" i.e.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match=".">
    <xsl:sequence select="?members?1"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. But I stuck in How to rename the Key name after fetching it. e.g. suppose I fetched the value of 1st index of members array. while populating the result the "name" field should be renamed to "MemberName".

Comment: Look at the functions on maps in the XPath 3.1 functions spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/, you can use `map:put($map, 'MemberName', $map?name) => map:delete('name')`. If you can't figure it out ask it as a new, separate questions.